# Hide Textblock if <Run> is empty WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `TextBlock` that i want to hide if property `Commission.Vehicle.Owner.Name` is empty. The code look like this. Of course this doesn't work, the `TextBlock` property Text will always be empty..

```
<Style x:Key="CollapsableTextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
           <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource CollapsableTextBlock}">
    <Run Text="Owner: "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Commission.Vehicle.Owner.Name}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Anyone with an idea? Thanks!

Comment: Run's Text is a property, not a dependency property so you can't bind it. You could probably bypass the limitation using the Tag DP and a converter

Comment: Oh, okey. Have to think in a different direction then. Thank you for the answer. @nkoniishvt

Comment: @nkoniishvt From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.text(v=vs.110).aspx): *Starting in the .NET Framework 4, the Text property of the Run object is a dependency property*

Comment: @Clemens good to know, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A DataTrigger should work:

```
<Style x:Key="CollapsableTextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Commission.Vehicle.Owner.Name}" Value="">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: This works. The `DataTrigger` was the key. Thank you! Will accept this as correct answer in 5min.